# Serialize data in file

Tags: bash, serialization, command-line

I need to add a portion to the beginning of every line in a file.

if my data is

```
Wombat
muskrat
gobbledegook
...
tomatopaste
```

I need to make it

```
000000001   Wombat
000000002   muskrat
000000003   gobbledegook
...
000009982   tomatopaste
```

to work with a specific machine. I can do it with excel, but a command line solution would be preferred so I can integrate it into a script. Any suggestions? Also this is a smaller file. I would also need to make it work with files upwards of 1 million lines. Which, at that point, excel handles extremely poorly (hit go and go to lunch poorly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need the numbers zero-padded as you have them, `awk` is probably the best solution:

```
awk '{printf "%09d ", NR}1' file.txt
```

Awk is a series of `condition{action}` pairs. For each line in the input file, the conditions are evaluated in order and if any is true, the corresponding action is evaluated. One or the other may be omitted. If a condition is omitted the action is performed every line; if an action is omitted, the current line is printed. Our first pair here is `{printf...}`, which is just an action; since there is no condition, it is evaluated every line. `printf` is a pretty universal function, printing the subsequent information according to the format string passed. We pass here `%09d`, which says the argument should be an integer (`d`), printed zero-padded (`0`) to nine digits (`9`); `%` starts a format specifier. The argument given, `NR`, is the `N`umber of `R`ows seen so far in the input. Finally, we have `1`, which is the next condition, always true. As mentioned earlier, lacking an explicit action, the current line is printed.

Comment: agreed. nice and simple. Ironic that I had meant to say batch, but I'm also running cygwin. so this works great.

Comment: hey, it works perfect, but would you mind throwing out a quick how it works?

Answer (score 1):

Bash-only solution:

```
 ( while read -r; do printf "%09u   %s\n" $((++i)) "$REPLY" ; done ) < file.txt
```

---

**Edit:** The above relies on the fact that `i` is either uninitialized, or has a value of 0.  This is a bit safer (and obviates the need for a `()` subshell:

```
i=0; while read -r; do printf "%09u   %s\n" $((++i)) "$REPLY" ; done < file.txt
```

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf - to keep the `i` variable in its own scope.  This assumes i is not initialized - and bash will automatically give it a value of 0 when first used.  But you can argue this relies on too much implicit behaviour, so I will give an update.